# Dual Monitor setup partially working with Mac Mini

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt, displayport, vga-adapter

I have a 2009 Mac Mini A1283.

I have 2 displays hooked up.

1) Mini Display Port -> Mini Display to DVI (female) adapter -> DVI Cable (male to male) -> DVI input on monitor

2) Mini-DVI Port -> Mini-DVI to VGA (female) -> VGA cable (male to male) -> VGA input on monitor

My second monitor only has VGA input so I have no choice but to use Mini-DVI to VGA

I wonder is this causing my problem which is:

My DVI monitor works fine. My VGA monitor shows a blank screen. My mac mini is picking up both monitors however, with the option of mirroring displays etc. Whatever option I choose (mirror/second display) it still shows a blank screen.

Any ideas why this is? Is it because of the VGA? Or the mix between VGA and DVI? If so what is a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your Mac Mini has a NVIDIA GeForce 9400M graphics card which uses either 128 or 256 MB of DDR3 SDRAM shared with your computer's main RAM.

If you're wanting to simultaneously use the Mini-DVI port and the Mini DisplayPort, then your Mac Mini needs to be set up as follows:

- Use the Mini-DVI port to connect a DVI or VGA display at 1920x1200 pixels
- Use the Mini DisplayPort (with an optional Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI adapter) to connect a dual-link DVI display at 2560x1600 pixels

If you've got the right resolutions set and are using the correct cables, then you can try resetting the NVRAM to see if that resolves the issue.

Here’s how to reset the NVRAM on your computer:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the 
   <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You
   have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again and you here the startup 
   chime.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try resetting the NVRAM. I've also heard resetting the PRAM might help. I do have the ports and cables set up as you said, is it OK to mix VGA and DVI?

Comment: Resetting NVRAM did not work unfortunately

Comment: My DVI monitor is 1600x900 and VGA is 1600x1050

Comment: Also note that my mouse leaves the first display and enters the second display. However the second screen is still blank

Comment: Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). The process for resetting them is exactly the same. What happens if you change the screen resolution for the VGA display? I'd try different resolutions and refresh rates (if you have the option).

Comment: I can't figure out how to change the resolution. I clicked scaled and changed from there but not sure if that affected the second display. I also tried booting in safe mode and no luck

Comment: If the VGA screen is your second display, then hold the Option key down while clicking on Scaled. This _should_ give you the options for the second screen.

Comment: I tried this and it changed the resolution for the first display. I can't tell if it affected the second display because it stayed black

Comment: I would select each resolution one by one to see if any makes a difference. By the way, what exact model of display is the VGA one?

Comment: I'll try that now.. model is AOC 2216sw

Comment: No luck with changing resolutions. Is it possible the connector is broken?

Comment: Well it could be a number of things. Yes it could be the port, but the cable is more likely to be a problem than the port. Also, how much RAM does your Mac have? What about the VGA screen - have you tested it with another computer? If you can't test it, what happens if you only connect the VGA screen to your Mac Mini? Can you get it to work and, if so, with what resolutions and refresh rates?

Comment: Yes, the screen works with my other laptop using VGA. My Mac has 6GB RAM. The VGA doesn't work with the Mac even when connected on its own. I feel like it could be the mini-DVI port because it's very hard to plug in. I really need to push it hard.

Comment: But the port seems to work, since the OS picks up the second display.

Comment: If you're having to push hard then you're not plugging the right cable into it. Are you sure about the cable you're using? Also, what laptop are you using (Mac/PC)? If it's a Mac, what exact model and what settings are you using?

Comment: The laptop is PC. I'm positive it is the correct cable. It is Mini-DVI, my other monitor uses the mini-DP. And also if it was not the correct cable I'm sure the OS wouldn't recognize both monitors.

Comment: I did look up your monitor the other day and, if I recall correctly, there was an input source button (or option in the menu). Have you tried switching input sources to see what happens? Also, you may be able to reset the screen from within its own menu options - if so that could be worth a try. I have to admit when I checked their website they didn't have a lot by way of Mac support and I think they had a _silly statement_ somewhere about having to download the plug 'n' play driver for Mac (that's silly because that's **not** how plug 'n' play works!).

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought all monitors were standard and compatible with mac. There is only one input source, that is VGA. But yes I did try messing with the monitor controls as much as I could. No luck though. I really hope I didn't waste my money on this monitor.